# When i am puting mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) in while loop to retrive data from database .the loop is iterate infinitly. why is it happening

Tags: php-7.3

When I put `mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)` inside variable `$row`, and then put `$row` into `while` loop `while($row)`. The loop is iterating infinitely.

But when I put whole initialization `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))` in `while` loops condition then its shows all of the values properly.

Why is it so?

```
//wrong code
while($row)
{
    print_r( $row );
}
```

```
//right code
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_select))
{
    print_r( $row  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `while` statement checks whether the expression in the braces evaluates to FALSE or not. Since `$row` is neither NULL, FALSE, 0 or empty string - it evaluates to TRUE, and so the `while` loops forever.

When you put the whole expression `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_select)` it first calls the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, then assigns the result to `$row` and finally checks the result for TRUE/FALSE. And since `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` returns NULL when there are no more records to fetch - the `while` loop stops.

Comment: [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) returns NULL not FALSE when there are no records.